# How to reset FCKeditor with reset button in PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, fckeditor

See the below image.

I have added a reset button at the end of form.

When user press "reset" I can clear all inputs.

But I don't know how to clear this FCKeditor values.

[Image](http://img66.imageshack.us/img66/7987/picture1c.png)

Comment: Seeing that reset button brought back some memories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think:

```
var fckEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('your-fckeditor-textbox-id'); 
fckEditor.EditorDocument.body.innerHTML = '';
```

will do what you want

Comment: Actually, I want to reset by java script. There is some problem with ' (single quote). When I press reset, fckeditor some times have default values ( when in modify/edit entry mode ).

Comment: This *is* JavaScript. Just put the code above in your 'reset' function.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I ran into the same issue recently and the idea of modifying the iframe contents directly bothers me.  Thankfully, the api provides us with a method for setting the value without resorting to hacking:

```
var editor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('your-textbox');
editor.SetHTML('');
```

As Mark B suggests in his comment on his own post, you can put this in a function and call it in the reset handler for your form:

```
<script>
function resetEditor() {
    var editor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('your-textbox');
    editor.SetHTML('');
}
</script>
<form onreset="resetEditor();">
```